# How to make Game Menu buttons disable others?

Tags: python, interface, game-engine

I'm still very new to Blender and trying to make a game menu currently. Imagine 9 buttons in a 3 by 3 grid. I need it to where you can only choose one button per column and per row. For example:

1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9

If you chose 1, then you wouldn't be able to choose 2, 3, 4, or 7. This would leave you with 5, 6, 8, and 9. If you then chose 8 the last option available would be 6.

I'm fairly certain this is possible, I just don't know where to start.

Comment: Which game engine do you use? Blender have no game engine since v2.80 released back in mid-2019, so either you use an older version of Blender, or a modern fork of Blender with a game engine like UPBGE, but otherwise you can't do that in Blender.

Comment: I'm using UPBGE, my bad. I still call it Blender, oops. ^ ^"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to better indicate it. Also include what you made so far.